# Downloading a file with Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, download, filesystems

Despite the many examples found on the documentation or in this forum, I can't find a way to download a file using Cordova...

First, I get the rootFS:

```
function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    console.log("got filesystem");
    // save the file system for later access
    console.log(fileSystem.root.fullPath);
        // displays "/" on desktop
        // displays "file:///mnt/sdcard" on android with SD Card
    window.rootFS = fileSystem.root;
}

document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {                
    window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, function(){
        console.log("error getting LocalFileSystem");
    });
}, false);
```

The upload script:

```
// Creating the image directory
imageDir = rootFS.getDirectory("imagesContent", {create: true},
    function(){
        // Success
    },
    function(error){
        console.log("ERROR getDirectory");
        console.log(error);
    }
);

// Creating and Downloading the image
    imgFile = imageDir.getFile(filename, {create: true, exclusive: true},
        function (){     
            var localPath = rootFS.fullPath+'/imagesContent/'+filename;
            fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();        
            fileTransfer.download('http://example.com/images/'+filename,
                localPath,
                function(entry) {
                    console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
                },
                function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    console.log('download error: ' + error.code);
                    console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                    console.log("download error target " + error.target);
                }
            );
        },
        function (error){
            console.log("ERROR getFile");
            console.log(error);
        }
    );
```

I get this error in the console:Uncaught TypeError:

```
Cannot call method 'getFile' of undefined
```

The uri is authorized in config.xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is with this line: `imageDir = rootFS.getDirectory("imagesContent", {create: true},function(), function())`  I don't think the call to `getDirectory` is supposed to actually return the directory name, like what you expect, which is why your `imageDir` object is undefined.

It might be easier for you to use the FileTransfer.download() method to download stuff from your server: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var uri = encodeURI("http://some.server.com/download.php");

fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    filePath,
    function(entry) {
        console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
    },
    false,
    {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: This is what I tried to do. But I need to configure the value of `filePath`. And it is a directory which might have to be created. So I followed this other example given in the [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#Flags).

Comment: I got it; I misunderstood at first. I had to remove the extra `getFile` function. However, I noticed that the new directory is created in the SD card. Isn't there a way to use the application directory?

Comment: Hi @Yako
To answer your question, you can use the FileSystem object provided by Cordova, and with the attribute fileSystem.files, you can use the applications file directory. More info here:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#android

Answer (score 0):

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var uri = encodeURI("http://some.server.com/download.php");

fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    filePath,
    function(entry) {
        console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
    },
    false,
    {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
        }
    }
);
```

I use it but  success and download is completed but not found image in y app